# Export max NDVI date layer as TIFF in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to export a layer containing NDVI max value and the NDVI max date of each pixel. the visualization layer is good, but when it is exported to TIFF, I can't use it in GIS software (I use QGIS). The value is nan.

```
var geometry = 
/* color: #d63000 */
/* shown: false */
/* displayProperties: [
  {
    "type": "rectangle"
  }
] */
ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[107.43022430567432, -6.146478462634124],
      [107.43022430567432, -6.164910996249429],
      [107.46043670801807, -6.164910996249429],
      [107.46043670801807, -6.146478462634124]]], null, false);

var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED");
var kecamatan = 'Kutawaluya' //  kecamatan 
//ROI
var ROI = geometry
Map.centerObject(ROI, 12)
var addNDVI = function(image){
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8A', 'B4']).rename('ndvi')
  return image.addBands(ndvi)
}
var S2 = S2.map(addNDVI)
var S2 = S2.select('ndvi')
var MOD = S2
          .filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-12-31')
          .filterBounds(ROI)

// Define a list of start dates, end dates, and periods
var startDate = '2018-01-01'; // replace with your start date
var endDate = '2022-12-31'; // replace with your end date

var half_year_periods = [];

for (var year = parseInt(startDate.slice(0, 4)); year <= parseInt(endDate.slice(0, 4)); year++) {
  half_year_periods.push([year + '-04-01', year + '-09-30', 'dry_' + year]);
  half_year_periods.push([year + '-10-01', (year + 1) + '-03-31', 'rain_' + year]);
}
// loop over each half-year period
for (var i = 0; i < half_year_periods.length; i++) {
  var period = half_year_periods[i];
  var start = period[0];
  var end = period[1];
  var label = period[2];
  
  // Filter the Sentinel 2 image collection for the current period
  var MOD = S2
    .filterDate(start, end)
    .filterBounds(ROI)
  
  // Compute the maximum NDVI for the current period
  var addDate = function(image) {
    return image.addBands(ee.Image.constant(ee.Number.parse(image.date().format("YYYYMMdd"))).rename('time').float());
  };
  var NDVI = MOD.map(addDate)
  var array = NDVI.toArray()
  var axes = { image:0, band:1 }
  var sort = array.arraySlice(axes.band, 0, 1);
  var sorted = array.arraySort(sort);
  var length = sorted.arrayLength(axes.image)
  var values = sorted.arraySlice(axes.image, length.subtract(1), length);
  var max = values.arrayProject([axes.band]).arrayFlatten([['ndvi', 'time']])
  var ndviMax = max.select(0)
  var time = max.select(1)
    //print(time.bandTypes())
  var time_float=time.toFloat()
  time_float = time_float.setDefaultProjection(time_float.projection())
  print(time_float.bandTypes())
  // Add the NDVI max value and time layer to the map
  Map.addLayer(ndviMax.clip(ROI), {min: 0, max: 1}, 'NDVI max value - ' + period)
  Map.addLayer(time_float.clip(ROI).randomVisualizer(), {}, 'NDVI time for max - ' + period)
  // Export the NDVI max value and time layers as images
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: ndviMax.clip(ROI),
    description: kecamatan + '_NDVI_max_' + label,
    scale: 100,
    region: ROI
  });

  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: time_float.clip(ROI),
    description: kecamatan + '_NDVI_time_' + label,
    scale: 100,
    region: ROI,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326'
  });
}
// Define a list to store the images
var image_list = []

// Loop over the list of start dates, end dates, and periods
for (var i = 0; i < half_year_periods.length; i++) {
  var start_date = half_year_periods[i][0]
  var end_date = half_year_periods[i][1]
  var period = half_year_periods[i][2]
  
  // Filter the Sentinel 2 image collection for the current period
  var MOD = S2
    .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
    .filterBounds(ROI)
  
  // Compute the maximum NDVI for the current period
  var addDate = function(image) {
    return image.addBands(ee.Image.constant(ee.Number.parse(image.date().format("YYYYMMdd"))).rename('time').float());
  };
  var NDVI = MOD.map(addDate)
  var array = NDVI.toArray()
  var axes = { image:0, band:1 }
  var sort = array.arraySlice(axes.band, 0, 1);
  var sorted = array.arraySort(sort);
  var length = sorted.arrayLength(axes.image)
  var values = sorted.arraySlice(axes.image, length.subtract(1), length);
  var max = values.arrayProject([axes.band]).arrayFlatten([['ndvi', 'time']])
  
  // Add the period name as a band to the image
  var period_band = ee.Image(0).byte().rename('period').set('period', period);
  var max_with_period = max.addBands(period_band);
  
  // Add the image to the list of images
  image_list.push(max_with_period);
  
  // Add the image to the list of images
  
  image_list.push(max_with_period);
  // Add the ndviMax and time image to the list
 // image_list.push(max)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute your addDate function with this one:

```
  var addDate = function(image) {
  var timeImage = image.metadata('system:time_start').rename('timestamp').
  divide(1000) //from miliseconds to seconds 
  var timeImageMasked = timeImage.updateMask(image.mask().select(0))
  return image.addBands(timeImageMasked)
  };
```

Using this function, the pixels values are POSIX time. In case you do not know what POSIX is, The Unix epoch (or Unix time or POSIX time or Unix timestamp) is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970. For example in one raster, I get this pixel value 1545362432, if I check in https://www.epochconverter.com/ I find out it means Mon, 24 Jul 2023 06:32:34 GMT.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it. Do you thin it is possible for me to use that pixel value as startdate for filtering images with enddate that i define later. So each pixel will get unique filtering date

Comment: I don't know, I have never done that, but it seems difficult.